# Boolean implies another

Tags: boolean, logic, truthtable

Is there a programming language in which we can write something like:

```
a => b
```

to compute implication? (where `a` and `b` are booleans)

The closest I can find is in Scala:

```
a <= b
```

But it looks completely different from the actual meaning of "implication".

Comment: If you're interested in a Boolean expression for `a -> b`, then you can use that fact that it is "true table equivalent" to `(not a) or b`. So in `C`, the equivalent of `a -> b` would be, `!a || b`.

Comment: yes, I know this fact. But it is not as nice as something like an arrow.

Comment: Procedural languages I know of don't have an explicit `a -> b` as it wouldn't really add a lot of value as a "pure logical expression". Ultimately, the programmer would really mean `(not a) or b` if they're looking for that type of truth value, and it's more understandable. Of course, `if-then` statements occur all the time procedurally and, therefore, are ubiquitous (I realize that's not the same thing). Prolog has an implication (`->`), but it's not quite the same as a boolean expression of other languages.

Comment: I don't agree with the fact that this would not add value to the logical expressions. I asked this question because I sometimes face logical expressions which would be more meaningful if I wrote them using arrows than (not a) or b. In my case, `if((condition1 => condition2) && (!condition1 => condition3)) statement` looks better than `if((!condition1 || condition2) && (condition1 || condition3)) statement`

Comment: In C++ you can define an operator and make it work that way. I only say it's "limited use" because if I see `if (A => B)` in code, in my mind I'd be translating it into `(not A) or B` to figure out what it does. But that's because I'm not used to thinking that "false implies true" is true. And it's fairly brief to write `!A || B` versus `A => B` so the motivation to introduce a new operator isn't high. At least I'd speculate that's why it's not prevalent in procedural languages (and possibly to avoid confusion with actual procedural `if-then` constructs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the winner is Scala:

```
implicit class BooleanMagic(val b: Boolean) extends AnyVal {
  def ==>(other: =>Boolean) = !b || other
}
```

Thanks to that:

```
> true ==> false
res0: Boolean = false

> false ==> (throw new Exception("I'm the president"))
res1: Boolean = true
```

*Edit* I also found Dafny and probably most other mathematical languages:

```
print true ==> false;

false
```

Answer (score 1):

Another language which supports this is Groovy (from version 5.0.0-alpha-4):

```
groovy:000> true ==> false
===> false
groovy:000> false ==> throw new Exception('Boom!')
===> true
```